# Highcharts use dateTime for chart generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using high-charts library to draw charts on my project.

> and i am facing an issue while displaying labels on X axis.

Graph is being drawn efficiently as per the values but X axis labels are not good and not as i want.

The Data is as below:

**seriesData**

```
Wed May 25 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),983.49,
Thu May 26 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),1000.3,
Fri May 27 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),996.24,
Sat May 28 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),996.75,
Sun May 29 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),996.75,
Mon May 30 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),1001.75,
Tue May 31 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),999.86,
Wed Jun 01 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),1003.16,
Thu Jun 02 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),996.35,
Fri Jun 03 2016 17:19:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),990.99
```

**And Highcharts JS is as below**

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
   global: 
      {
        useUTC: currentTime.getUTCHours()==currentTime.getHours()        
      }
}); 
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
       chart: {
            renderTo: 'linechartjs',
            zoomType: 'x'
         },
        title: {
             text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
             type: 'datetime',
             dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                  minute: '%H:%M',
                  hour: '%H:%M',
                  day: '%e. %b',
                  week: '%e. %b',
                  month: '%e.%m',
                  year: '%e.%m.%Y'
              },
         },
         yAxis: {
            title: {
                 text: ''
             },
             min: minY,
             max: maxY,
             tickInterval: increment,
                opposite: true
         },
         plotOptions: {
             line: {
                 dataLabels: {
                     enabled: false
                  },
                  marker: {
                     enabled: false
                  },
                  enableMouseTracking: false
              }
          },
          exporting: {
             buttons: {
                 contextButton: {
                     enabled: false
                 }
              }
           },
           credits: {
               enabled: false
           },
           series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
                name: '',
                color: '#333',
                data: seriesData,
           }]
      });
  })
```

The X axis labels are as below:

[image]

> X axis labels shall be in Date Format like 25.05, 26.05 .. and so on

Comment: The above graph is made if i push data like `seriesData.push(x,y)` but if i push data like `seriesData.push(x.getTime(),y)` then X axis labels comes correctly but then line graph is drawn in different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Readers:** This answer has been updated based on further input from the
>   questioner. Please see below.

It looks like you don't need all of that code for your `dateTimeLabelFormat` attribute.

From your example, it seems what you want is two-digit day and two-digit month. In that case, all you need for your x-axis labels is:

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    day: '%d.%m'
}
```

Here's an example fiddle (from a Highcharts demo) with this label format: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/zxt39L7g/

And here's the resulting chart:

[image]

Please let me know if this is helpful for you.

> I did some further research based on the comments **Gags** provided
>   and came up with additional label formatting and intervals. These
>   settings can be changed based on what the user chooses in a dropdown
>   menu (see the comments).

First, I created the dropdown menu:

```
<select id="chooseDateRange">
    <option value="">- choose a date range -</option>
    <option value="1day">one day</option>
    <option value="1week">one week</option>
    <option value="1month">one month</option>
    <option value="1year">one year</option>
    <option value="5years">five years</option>
</select>
```

Second, I created a Javascript function to set and define values based on what the user chose in this menu:

```
// initialize local variables for the chart's options
var selectedPointInterval = 0;
var selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'day';

// set values based on which date range the user chose
function setDateRangeAndLabels(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case "1day":
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'day';
            selectedPointInterval = 1;
            break;
        case "1week":
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'day';
            selectedPointInterval = 7;
            break;
        case "1month":
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'month';
            selectedPointInterval = 1;
            break;
        case "1year":
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'year';
            selectedPointInterval = 1;
            break;
        case "5years":
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'year';
            selectedPointInterval = 5;
            break;
        default:
            selectedPointIntervalUnit = 'day';
            selectedPointInterval = 1;
            break;
    }    
    chartOptions.plotOptions.series.pointInterval = selectedPointInterval;
    chartOptions.plotOptions.series.pointIntervalUnit = selectedPointIntervalUnit;
};
```

Third, I set the chart's options to a variable called `chartOptions'. I moved the attributes that set`pointStart`to`plotOptions.series` to make them universal for all series.

```
// define the chart's options
var chartOptions = {
    plotOptions: {
        series: { pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1) }
    },
    xAxis: { 
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%d.%m',
            week: '%d.%m',
            month: '%m.%y',
            year: '%m.%y'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
};
```

Finally, I created code to draw the chart upon first loading the page, as well as a jQuery function to redraw it based on the user choosing a new range from the dropdown menu:

```
// draw the chart
setDateRangeAndLabels('1day');
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);

// redraw the chart based on new date range
    $('#chooseDateRange').change(function (){
    setDateRangeAndLabels(this.value);
  chart = $('#container').highcharts(chartOptions);
});
```

Here's the complete fiddle for review: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/zxt39L7g/

> **Please note:** This will only change the x-axis labels, intervals, and
>   default tooltip text for the data that the chart is given. To get data
>   that's relevant to the date intervals chosen, you'll need to also
>   dynamically change the series data based on the user's choice.

Comment: HI,,, Thanks for the answer and i have seen this example earlier also but i need you to look on my data as  have many data for single day as well and so on...

Comment: @Gags OK. How small do you want the measurements for each data point to be? Also, what is the desired format? Something like YY.MM.DD:HH.MM.SS?

Comment: I have a dropdown which is used to select period of data to be selected ie. from 1 day, 1week, 1 month, 1 year and 5 years. That is why i have so many values used in `datetime` format on X axis..  There is no fixed measurement and data points are dynamic depends on selection as explained above. Desired format will be 01.05 02.05 and so on..

Comment: @Gags That's helpful information. I have a potential solution in mind; give me a bit and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: have u got any chance to look into this?

Comment: @Gags I've updated my answer with some additional coding that I hope will be useful to you. Please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: this is working fine... but i have figure out my data.push methods needed correction. I pushed the data as object like `data.push({x:x, y:y});`  .. Thanks for your reply